# .bat file to move multiple files from one directory to another and rename instead of overwriting

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Forgive me if this is a simple question, but I've been out of practice for a few years!
I am creating a .bat file at work that will require me to move all files from one directory to another and if any conflicts arise, to add the date to the filename instead of overwriting it. All in all, I want to keep every file, even if they are duplicates. TIA for any help!

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: The question would be "what is the command(s)  I'm looking for that would allow me to move multiple files from one directory to another without overwriting and instead renaming?"   I've only been able to get it to work with a single file.

Comment: Please read the help topic [how to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0):

```
MD "C:\NewFolder"

CD "%userprofile%\desktop"

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a-d /b "%userprofile%\desktop"') do If not exist C:\NewFolder\%%A (copy "%%A" "C:\NewFolder\%%A") Else copy "%%A" "C:\NewFolder\%%A%date:/=%"
```

It ugly but it works and should get you started. See `dir /?`, `for /?`, and  `if /?`. Note you have to change directories for it to work.